# iPhone SDK: SDWebImageDownloader Crashing

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, sdwebimage

I'm using the SDWebImageDownloader library to download images asynchronously.
The problem i'm having is when I click the back button before the images finish download the app is crashing on the following line in the SDWebImage Class:

```
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageDownloaderDidFinish:)])
```

This is how i'm using it in my code:

```
sdDownloader = [[SDWebImageDownloader downloaderWithURL:headerImgURL delegate:self]retain];
```

What is causing it to crash? I'm retaining it and i'm not releasing it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you are retaining "it", what do you mean by "it"?  If it's crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when you try to send a message to `delegate`, it's likely that `delegate` is a dangling pointer because it's being released prematurely.  What is retaining `delegate`?  What is releasing `delegate`?

Comment: i'm retaining sdDownloader and i'm not releasing the sdDownloader object anywhere so there's no way it is being released prematurely.

Comment: I'm not talking about `sdDownloader`, I'm talking about `delegate`.

Comment: well i'm implementing all of the SDWebImageDownloader delegate methods, so i'm not sure how to release or retain a delegate

Comment: I'm not talking about implementing delegate methods, I'm talking about retaining the delegate.  You are passing `self` in as the delegate.  What is retaining this object?  What is releasing it?

Comment: If nothing is retaining it, then it will be deallocated as soon as it goes out of scope.  That will leave `sdDownloader` with a dangling pointer to deallocated memory where it thinks its delegate will be.  When it's trying to send a message to its delegate, it's dereferencing this garbage pointer, hence the crash.

Comment: You retain objects by passing a `retain` message to them.  I suggest you read [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) in the official documentation.